# Set Parse "reset password" message content

Tags: parse-platform

Anyone know if there is a way to specify content of message sent to users by Parse when resetting password ( PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground ] ) ?

Following is pseudo code to create user and asking for a password reset

```
// create user
PFUser* pUser   =   [ [ PFUser alloc ] init ];

pUser.username  =   @"Batman";
pUser.password  =   @"Gr34tT0ys";
pUser.email     =   @"batman@arkham.com";

[ pUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock: ^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    ...
} ];

// ask for password reset
[ PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground: @"batman@arkham.com" block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    ...;
} ];
```

Actual message is:

> Hi,
>
> You requested to reset your password for YOUR_APP_NAME.
>
> Click here to reset it:
>
> A_RESET_LINK

At a minimum, I'd like its content to be localized.

Ideally i'd like to provide Parse with email's text

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you'd need to implement your own functionality.  You could use a Cloud Function, which sends email with Mandrill/Mailgun, directs them to a page on Parse Hosting with some token, which validates and allows changing the password.  The provided reset password feature does not currently support modification.

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#mailgun
https://parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#mandrill

https://parse.com/docs/hosting_guide#hosting

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer @Fosco.

Comment: @hsarret did you end up figuring anything out regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the email templates in the Parse.com dashboard for your app.

Go to your apps dashboard and click:

- Settings (in the top tabs)
- Email settings (left nav)

You can now set the email templates.

Unfortunately I don't think you can localise these!